# Get all records from tbl1 and matching (or the next close) records from tbl2, match is based on Client# and Date from tbl1 to tbl2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to match (or next greater match)from Tbl1 to Tbl2.

Criteria is

1. Extract all records from tbl1 and close or equal match from tbl2
2. Find Matching records from tbl2 (match is based on ClientNo and/or date)
3. tbl2 match should be based on date greater than or equal to the tbl1 date.
4. Results should not have any duplicates from tbl1 or tbl2

First match should be the first date2 in tbl2 that is greater or equal to date1 in tbl1

If there are more than one records on the same date than it should pick the next greater or equal date based on RefNO in tbl2.

tbl1 contains

```
RecNo  ClientNo   Date1
-----------------------------
  4      1001      2/6/2017
  3      1001      2/4/2018
  1      1001      2/5/2018
  2      1001      2/5/2018
  5      1002      3/8/2018
  9      1002      3/9/2018
 10      1002      4/11/2019
```

tbl2 contains

```
RecNo   ClientNo   Date2      RefNo
-----------------------------------
   1    1001       2/5/2017     1
   4    1001       2/5/2018     2
   2    1001       2/5/2018     4
   3    1001       2/6/2018     5
   5    1002       3/9/2018     1
   6    1002       4/10/2019    2
```

Query result

```
RecNoTbl1   ClientNo   Date1       RecNoTbl2   Date2     RefNo
---------------------------------------------------------------
    4        1001      2/6/2017      4         2/5/2018    2
    3        1001      2/4/2018      2         2/5/2018    4
    1        1001      2/5/2018      3         2/6/2018    5
    2        1001      2/5/2018      NULL      NULL       NULL
    5        1002      3/8/2018      5         3/9/2018    1
    9        1002      3/9/2018      6         4/10/2019   2
   10        1002      4/11/2019     NULL      NULL       NULL
```

I tried with ROW OVER PARTITION but that didn't work.

Comment: What if you can't match all records in the second table?

Comment: Please show us your code attempt.

Comment: Below is my code for one clientno 1001...does not produce the results as expected


With cl as(
Select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by clientno order by Clientno,date1) as rwno
from tbl1
where ClientNo = '1001'),

tr as(
Select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by clientno order by Clientno,date2,refno) as rwno
from tbl2
where ClientNo = '1001')

select *
from Cl
left join tr on  cl.clientno  = tr.ClientNo 
where tr.date2 >= cl.date1
and  cl.rwno = tr.rwno
and cl.ClientNo = '1001'

Comment: @Gordon Linoff , if there are no matching records then it should produce NULL results for all records in tbl1..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left join query like this

```
Select tb1.*, tb2.* from table1 tb1 
Left join table2 tb2 ON tb1.clientno = tb2.clientno Where tb1.date>=tb2.dare
```

For unique you can use distinct 
Like this: `select distinct tb1.title`

Check [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

For more info of **distinct**

And sorry if am not really detailed about things.    I am posting from phone.

Comment: I just updated it with where statement to match great or equal for tb1's date to tb2's date

Comment: @ man of knowledge,, thanks for your response but your code doesn't give me the expected results,..it gives me multiple record from tbl1 and tbl2 . The total number of records should be equal to records in tbl1. <b>DISTINCT</b> wont work.

Comment: what about adding a group by statement at the end ?

Comment: It wont work, because the results I want is all records from tbl1 and only the matching records from tbl2. Match is on Client # and Date (equal or higher) once the record from  tbl2 is matched then it should not be matched to any other record in tbl1. In the end there should be one record from tbl1 and only one match record from tbl2.